# How to make cookies crispy?

Tags: baking, cookies

I'm looking to make very crispy thin, light, airy cookies. Kind of like dog-treats but for humans.

What makes some cookies chewy and other "snap"? What makes cookies "heavy"?

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/49592/what-determines-the-texture-of-cookies?rq=1

Comment: Do you have a recipe you're trying to make crispier, or are you open to any version? (For example, biscotti have away struck me as sort of like dog treats!)

Comment: Alton Brown covered much of this in the Good Eats episode 'Three Chips for Sister Marsha'.  [recipes](https://www.foodnetwork.com/shows/good-eats/episodes/three-chips-for-sister-marsha2) and [transcript](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season3/cookie/cookietranscript.htm)

Comment: Thin dough/batter will spread out more during baking, resulting in a crisper cookie.

Answer (score 1):

In my own cookie making experience, substituting margarine for butter yielded a crispier cookie than butter.  Sometimes too crispy.   [The Perfect Cookie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1940352959) dismisses non butter fats for cookies although they did suggest the trick of substituting a small amount of butter for liquid oil to increase chewiness.

The margarine cookies slump and get crispy and almost toasty/ fried.  If that sounds good, try making a batch of toll house cookies with margarine and see what you think.